# How to disable Google Chrome Canary forced search for 0.0.0.0 address

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-canary

When i am trying to navigate to url such as `http://0.0.0.0:3000/something`, canary does not allow me to do it, it just offers me to search with text that i typed in omnibox.
[image]

It happens only with address that started with 0.
[image]

And there is no such problem in stable version. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `0.0.0.0/8` block is reserved and only valid as a source addresses; Thus, it makes little sense to navigate to it, since that would be using it as a destination.
<sup>[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Special-use_addresses)</sup>

If a particular piece of software is listening for incoming connections on `0.0.0.0`, that generally means that it is listening on *all available network interfaces*. Simply substitute it for any IP address by which you can reach the target machine.

Comment: For some reason, i've seen some software manuals which invite the user to navigate to 0.0.0.0 where 127.0.0.1 would make sense. Apparently, on some platforms, it does work.